# How to create combo chart with Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Need to create a chart similar to the one you see here: http://imgbin.org/index.php?page=image&id=20802. So far managed to put together a jsfiddle that displays both charts but its far from complete.

How would you correctly place the bottom chart (column) over the first to achieve the effect you see in example? http://jsfiddle.net/e106L47h/6/

```
$(function () {
    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-ohlcv.json&callback=?', function (data) {

        // split the data set into ohlc and volume
        var ohlc = [],
            volume = [],
            dataLength = data.length,
            // set the allowed units for data grouping
            groupingUnits = [[
                'week',                         // unit name
                [1]                             // allowed multiples
            ], [
                'month',
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
            ]],

            i = 0;

        for (i; i < dataLength; i += 1) {
            ohlc.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][1], // open
                data[i][2], // high
                data[i][3], // low
                data[i][4] // close
            ]);

            volume.push([
                data[i][0], // the date
                data[i][5] // the volume
            ]);
        }


        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            navigator: {
                enabled: false
            },
            rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1,
                inputEnabled: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },           
            yAxis: [{
                height: '60%',
                lineWidth: 0
            }, {
               top: '65%',
                height: '35%',
                offset: 0,
                lineWidth: 0,
               // gridLineWidth: 0,
                labels:
                {
                  //enabled: false
                }
            }],

           series: [{
                type: 'candlestick',
                name: 'AAPL',
                data: ohlc,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }, {
                type: 'column',
                name: 'Volume',
                data: volume,
                yAxis: 1,
                dataGrouping: {
                    units: groupingUnits
                }
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the height 35%/65% split and show both series with the same baseline.

Then I would hide the volume axis to reduce clutter.

You can modify the height of the volume bars by setting the max of the second hidden axis rather than the height (I have used maxValue*3 to approximate your 35% height value).

Find the maximum value in the volume series like this:

```
    var maxVolume = Math.max.apply(Math, volume.map(function(v) { return v[1]}))
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cvezpup7/

Comment: I think you posted unmodified jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm assuming the 'max value' is defined in your jsfiddle?  The charts seem to still overlap on ranges greater than (3 months).

Comment: I've had a go at dynamically calculating the maximumm height of the volume bars depending on the ohlc range. It works pretty well apart from the 'All' selection, good luck: http://jsfiddle.net/cvezpup7/1/